# Remote Event Receivers not firing in case of Service to Service authentication scenario using Azure AD

Tags: office-365, provider-hosted-app, azure, remote-event-receiver

I have created a SharePoint app(Add in) with a RemoteEventReceiver subscribed to Item Added Event on a custom list. After installing app in office 365 I can log into portal and add item to list and it is firing RER event. Thanks to Office PnP Guys. It is SharePoint Provider hosted  app and hosted in Azure.

Now I have created a console application and registered this with AzureAD and assigned Office 365 Online API and Management API to this application talking to Office 365 via [Service to Service Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api)( Again thanks to PnP guys and ADAL). I am able to get the apponly tokens and read and write items of list but, List Item Add action(via CSOM) is not firing RER Item Added Event. **Am I missing any permissions in my Azure AD or is it by design RER cannot be fired in App only context scenario?**

Instead of Passing Apponly token if I pass my credentials to client context RER is getting fired.

Can some one shed some light on what I am missing in Service to Service Authentication scenario.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I am sorry,no I could not find a solution